# inheritance and custom logic in DTOs

Tags: java, design-patterns, dto

As I know, aim of DTOs usage is to keep plain object for transport data. Could you provide some argument for or against usage of inheritance and custom logic in DTOs. It makes code difficult to read this is what I found as disadvantage. On other hand it may reduce some code duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DTO - Data transfer object, should be easy data containers to provide between web layer and services layer for example. For my most advantage logic inside might be some validation rules and nothing more. Any business logic for sure.

Comment: What about inheritance, used just to avoid code duplication?

Comment: yea, i might be helpful if it reduce code.